# I run Bash with proxychains4; how can I cancel proxychains4?

Tags: linux, bash

In Ubuntu 16, if I want to use `bash` with `proxychains4` I enter the command:

```
proxychains4 -q /bin/bash
```

How can I stop using `proxychains4` after this? What is the command? Rebooting works but I don't want to reboot my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kamil Maciorowski answer is a good solution, but if you want to keep the current shell and only disable proxychains what you need to do is

```
unset LD_PRELOAD
```

Because what proxychains does is to preload that library to override system's connection functions.

I hope this helps

Comment: Note: this causes `proxychains4` not to affect new processes started from the shell from now on, but *the shell itself* is still proxified; e.g. new redirections in a form `>/dev/tcp/8.8.8.8/9999` will use `proxychains4`. So this does not literally "stops using `proxychains4`". Your answer is useful nevertheless; upvoted. You may edit my note into the answer if you want.

Comment: @optimus If you find this answer helpful then consider accepting it (see our short [tour] for guidance).

Answer (score 0):

Exit Bash:

- with `exit` builtin,
- or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (when the command line is empty).

This will terminate `bash` so you will end up in the *original* shell (in which you typed `proxychains4 …` earlier) which is unaffected by `proxychains4`.